# CodeIgniter routing issue, advice how to do it

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I'm not CI programmer, just trying to learn it. Maybe this is wrong approach, please advice.

my controller(not in sub directory) :

```
class Users extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

public function index($msg = NULL) {

        $this->load->helper(array('form'));

        $data['msg'] = $msg;

        $this->load->view('user/login' , $data);

    }

   public function process_logout() {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(base_url());
    }

}
```

And a route for login :

```
$route['user/login'] = 'users/index';
```

Problem is when I wanna logout, it shows me 404 because I do not have it in my route :

```
$route['user/process_logout'] = 'users/process_logout';
```

and in my view I put `<a href="users/process_logout">logout</a>`

When I add that, it works, and that is stuppid to add a route for everything. What I'm I doing wrong, please advice.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why you are trying to implement login feature in index() function. However since you said you are learning CI I'm telling something about **_remap()** function.

Before that. You can try the following routing:

```
$route['user/:any'] = 'users/$1';
$route['user/login'] = 'users/index';
```

If you want to take value immediately after controller segment you need to use _remap() function and this function may be solve your routing problem, i mean you don't need to set routing. Lets implement your code controller **'users'** using _remap() function.

```
class Users extends CI_Controller {

    private $sections = array('login', 'logout');

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    }

   public function _remap($method)
   {
        $section = $this->uri->segment(2);

        if(in_array($section, $this->sections))
            call_user_func_array(array($this, '_'.$section), array());

        else show_404(); // Showing 404 error
   }

   private function _login() 
   {
        $msg = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $this->load->helper(array('form'));
        $data['msg'] = $msg;
        $this->load->view('user/login' , $data);
    }

   public function _logout() {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(base_url());
    }

}
```